# Downloading in server without remote desktop connection

Tags: filter, ftp, download

I have Microsoft Windows Server 2003 and i can connect to it with remote desktop connection.

Internet connection speed is good in server. In my place some famous websites are blocked like youtube, and all file hosting websites.

I want to download my favorite files from these websites,but downloading speed is very low (after using VPN connection), so I decided to download my files in server first and next to download them by FTP to my PC.

My problem is that I have to connect to server remotely always. Is there anyway or software can does this for me? I do not want to connect remotely!

Comment: Be aware that corporate network admins block those sites because their content is not allowed.  By-passing security in the manner you are suggesting is usually grounds for termination.

Answer (score 0):

You have no other options just connect to remote desktop (or VNC, etc).

Or you can setup some very simple proxy on Windows server and point your browser(on your desk) to this proxy.Then traffic will go to your server first and then to your PC.Okay, this does not solve speed throught VPN, but you will not be blocked to restricted sites.If you know exact list of files (URLs) to download, there are many software which can do download work for you (simplest is DownThenAll in FF)